# how to open .tsv file in python (mac); UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 2: invalid start byte

Tags: python, macos, utf-8

just not able to read data in python which is a .tsv.7z file, any heads up would be appreciated. I am using mac os 10.13 macOS High Sierra. Thanks!!

```
train = pd.read_csv('/Users/sherrymukim/Documents/mercari/train.tsv', sep='\t',encoding='utf-8')

train = pd.read_csv('/Users/sherrymukim/Documents/mercari/train.tsv', sep='\t',encoding='utf-8') Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in train = pd.read_csv('/Users/sherrymukim/Documents/mercari/train.tsv', sep='\t',encoding='utf-8')

File "/Users/sherrymukim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

File "/Users/sherrymukim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 405, in _read parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)

File "/Users/sherrymukim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 764, in init self._make_engine(self.engine)

File "/Users/sherrymukim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 985, in _make_engine self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)

File "/Users/sherrymukim/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1605, in init self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)

File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 562, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.cinit (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:6175)

File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 781, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._get_header (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:9691)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 2: invalid start byte
```

Comment: The `.7z` extension indicates the file is compressed. What are you doing to decompress it?

Comment: I was just renaming the file by removing .7z from the name. Maybe that is a wrong approach.  How does one decompress this file? Thank you very much.

Comment: It's the wrong approach. The easiest way is to use some archiving utility to decompress the file – perhaps you can even just double-click it to do so (once you restored the file name with the ".7z" extension).

Comment: Yes, I just did downloaded an un-archiver. Thanks for the mention.